# Get location of point in different reference frame using quaternions

Tags: coordinate-systems, quaternions

This may be a trivial question but I am not very well versed with quaternions.

I have a camera which has a location and orientation in world coordinates. The location is (x,y,z) and the orientation is expressed using a quaternion. Now, within the cameras coordinate frame I have the location of a point relative to the camera.

How can I get the location (x,y,z) of this point relative to the global coordinate frame? The point itself has no orientation associated with it but I assume that I need to somehow use the cameras quaternion rotation to make the coordinate transform. How do I incorporate the change in rotation of the reference frame using the quaternion?

Thank you for your help!

[Image showing the position vector that I am looking for in grey.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b32nW.png)